# Linking to a non-entrypoint GWT page

Tags: url, gwt

Is there a way in GWT to make it so that external sources can link to pages that aren't EntryPoints and have not yet been visited?

The end goal is to allow users to provide URLs to other users that link to a page that is not an EntryPoint. An example is how the GWT history feature works, where after you visit a page (such as `http://<ip address>:<port>/MyEntryPointClass.html#NotEntryPointClass`), even if you click to a different page and then enter that URL into the address panel, it takes you back to that page. However, if you've never visited that page before, it just takes you back to the entry point page. I have only been able to find solutions where a GWT page links to an external source, and not the other way around which is what I need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Activities and Places pattern. In your entry point class add:

```
historyHandler.handleCurrentHistory();
```

and it will take your user to the default place if no place is specified in the URL, or to the place set in the URL.